# Best Data Structure for data captured monthly for 7 years - array of lists?

Tags: python

I'm new to python. Was a C developer a LONG time ago.
I'm learning Python as a personal project to self-educate during lockdown.

My project is reading a forum website and capturing posts per month in a specific forum.

I've made some progress and can scan the website, extract a count of posts and assign to a specific month. I don't have years defined yet. I just need help with the right data structure to represent all the years data.

What's the best way to represent a fixed range of 10 years of monthly data?

My preference is to stick to built-in capability as much as possible.

One suggestion was to use JSON, although I've been staring at the JSON docs and getting confused.

I search for python array of lists - answers got me confused.

```
year = {
    1: {"name": "Jan", "count": 0},
    2: {"name": "Feb", "count": 0},
    3: {"name": "Mar", "count": 0},
    4: {"name": "Apr", "count": 0},
    5: {"name": "May", "count": 0},
    6: {"name": "Jun", "count": 0},
    7: {"name": "Jul", "count": 0},
    8: {"name": "Aug", "count": 0},
    9: {"name": "Sep", "count": 0},
    10: {"name": "Oct", "count": 0},
    11: {"name": "Nov", "count": 0},
    12: {"name": "Dec", "count": 0}
}

# Testing

for month, data in year.items():
    print(year[month]["name"], year[month]["count"])
    year[month]["count"] = random.randrange(10)

print(year)
```

Comment: This is more opinion-centric than we general focus on here -- Stack Overflow is best for questions about *specific problems* with provably correct answers; questions about ideal practices, algorithm/structure selection, &c are more the domain of our sister site [programmers.se].

Comment: Understood. And thanks for the alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a fixed number of years, and as python native as possible, use a list of lists, for example `a = [[1,2],[3,4]]`.

```
nb_of_months_in_a_year = 12
nb_of_years = 10
counts = [[0 for i in range(nb_of_months_in_a_year)] for j in range(nb_of_years)]

# counts is now a list of lists, and can be viewed as a matrix with 10 rows and 12 colums. 1 row per year, 1 column per month
for year in counts:
    print(year)

# increment 4th year (counting from 0), februari (counting from 0):
counts[3][1] += 1
print(counts)

# get count in februari in all years:
total = 0
for year in counts:
  total += year[1]
print(total) # yields 1
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. 
I'm going to try your suggestion out now.